# Translate plugin/solution for EPiServer 7.x

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

Is there any translation tool for episerver 7 similar to [TranslateX](http://world.episerver.com/Download/Categories/Open-Source/TranslateX/)?

TranslateX does not seem to be compatible with episerver 7.

Comment: What is TanslateX and what are you using it for?

Comment: @ppittle there is a link in the question post that explains what translate x is.

Comment: EPiServer has a "Ready for translation" workflow, you could use this to help manage assigning things to be translated. More information about it here: http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/multilingual-website-episerver.aspx